# How to print bash's real execution path, i.e. something like type -f akin to type -a?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I imagine to invoke `type` with the option `-f` (follow) akin to `-a` (all).

Here are my questions:

1. Is there a Bash built-in to print how `bash` would execute a command?
2. Is there a Linux utility to print how any shell would execute a command?
3. Can the below shell function I'm using be simplified?

Given the following definitions and `/usr/local/bin/ls` being a link to `/usr/bin/ls`:

```
alias ls="\ls -h --color=auto"
alias lsa="ls -A"
alias lsh="lsa -I'*'"
```

`rcommand lsh` prints:

```
alias lsh='lsa -I'\''*'\'''
alias lsa='ls -A'
alias ls='\ls -h --color=auto'
link /usr/local/bin/ls
file /usr/bin/ls
```

Here is my shell function I defined in my .bashrc file:

```
function rcommand {
  declare -r a="${1#\\}"
  declare -r b="$(type -t "$a")"
  if [[ "$b" == alias && "$a" == "$1" ]]; then
    declare -r c="$(command -v "$a")"
    echo "$c"
    declare -r d="$(echo "$c" | sed "s/^.*='\\\\\\?\(\w\+\).*$/\1/")"
    if [[ "$d" == "$a" ]]; then
      rcommand  "\\$d"
    else
      rcommand  "$d"
    fi
  elif [[ "$b" == builtin || "$b" == function || "$b" == keyword ]]; then
    echo "$b $a"
  else
    declare -r c="$(declare -F "$a")"
    if [[ "$c" == "$a" ]]; then
      echo "function $a"
    else
      declare -r d="$(type -P "$a")"
      if [[ -h "$d" ]]; then
        echo "link $d"
        rcommand "$(readlink "$d")"
      elif [[ -e "$d" ]]; then
        echo "file $d"
      fi
    fi
  fi
}
```

Comment: here is `type` builtin in shell,

Comment: The `type` options `-p|-P|-t` are all pretty well readable by a machine. You are right about invoking `type` with or without the option `-a`.

Comment: you want jus print each executed comand ?

Comment: I want to print each command that would be executed in a format similar to the output of `rcommand lsh` as shown in my question.

Comment: in case of functions, do you want to print which commans will be runned by function ?

Comment: No, I only want to trace back aliases and links.

Comment: The `rcommand` function could improve as follows: 1. Remove the unecessary double quotes from the left operand of every `[[` expression because a lhs-operand is not treated as a Bash pattern. 2. Replace the `elif` case with 3 `==` operators `||` together with `$b =~ function|builtin|keyword`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean `set -x` for *tracing* command in `bash` and/or `sh` ?

Anyway, your script seem pretty and nice. There is my version with some alternatives...

```
function rcommand() {
  local b="$(type -t "$1")"
  case $b in
    alias )
          local c="$(command -v "$1")"
          echo $c
          local d=$(sed "s/^.*='\?\([^ ]\+\) .*$/\1/" <<<$c)
          if [[ "$d" == "$1" ]]; then
              rcommand  "\\$d"
          else
              rcommand  "$d"
          fi
          ;;
      builtin | function | keyword )
          echo "$b $1"
          ;;
      * )
          local a="${1#\\}"
          local c="$(declare -F "$a")"
          if [[ "$c" == "$a" ]]; then
              echo "function $a"
          else
              local d="$(type -P "$a")"
              if [ -h "$d" ]; then
                  echo "link $d"
                  rcommand "$(readlink "$d")"
              elif [ -e "$d" ]; then
                  echo "file $d"
              fi
          fi
  esac
}
```

Comment: @Tim Friske: I've simply `cut'n past` some part of your purpose, anyway, I don't understand your goal when you wote: `a="${1#\\}"` ... I think this code could be shorter.

Comment: With `a="${1#\\}"` I strip of a leading backslash from the command given as the 1st parameter. It signals my `rcommand` function that it should stop treating the command as an alias if it shadows a built-in, function, etc. Much like you can let bash bypass the `foo` alias by typing `\foo` in command position.

Comment: No, and yes I know about `set -x`, but I intent to have a quick way to probe the execution path from my interactive Bash shell for any given command. So the `rcommand` function should be seen more of an ad-hoc reporting tool at the user's disposition.

Comment: I didn't know you could redirect directly from a variable with `<<<`. Nice feature. I shall incorporate this into my off-line version.

Comment: Invoking your version with `rcommand \\lsh` still evaluates the aliases, whereas my version prints just an empty line. I deliberately added this behavior so the user can see if there is any other command apart from an alias. It looks like this difference is caused by the different regex.

Comment: @TimFriske: no, the regex was ok, I've  forgot `[ $1 == $a ]`.